# Removing sub-floor of hot mopped shower

Tags: shower

I have removed the tile in my master bath shower and found the shower was sealed by hot mop. I'm assuming I have to remove the subfloor and install fresh plywood. I'm wondering what's the best method of removing the tar covered plywood?

Comment: Photos would help. The usual routine is to cut around the outside and get rowdy with it. You might be able to sand or grind off the coating, though, or add underlayment.

Comment: Hot mop is really not sandable the asphalt plugs the sandpaper really fast. Cutting is the best method if it requires removal. I used to do hot mop roofing and the stuff is nasty any wood dust with goo on it can ruin carpet & clothing so make sure to tarp the flooring around where you will be working.